# Session timeout does not work at asp.net mvc 4 C# . Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session, authentication

For my web site I configured login session timeout for 1 week in web.config file

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime />

  <!-- Session keeps for 7 days -->
    <sessionState timeout="10080"></sessionState>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/" timeout="10080" slidingExpiration="true"/>
    </authentication>
  <!-- Configuration end  -->
</system.web>
```

Here is code for login

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string Login, string Password)
    {
        // empty passwords are not allowed
        if (Password == "")
            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());

        bool LoginResult = WebSecurity.Login(Login, Password, true);
        return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
    }
```

I login, close browser and open it again go to my web site -> user is logged in.
I close browser, wait some time (about 30 minutes) go to my web site -> user is logged off.
Why? Session should be stored for 7 days but we does not have even 30 minutes. 
Whan can be the source of problem?

**Edit 1** *The main idea is that I want to go back to the site in several days and still open it with logged in user*

Comment: Are you really sure you want to keep data in memory for 7 days after the last visit?

Comment: Yes, it is internal web site which has 3 users only and I'm tired to enter credentials every time

Comment: We have the same issue when we moved from mvc3 to 4.

Comment: @Vitalii could you please let me know what configuration do we need to change. I'm on the same page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Possibly, your `IIS` would have been configured to 20 minutes of `TimeOut`.

Change the `IIS` session timeout to <s>1 week</s> 24 hours, which I hope will solve your problem.

Refer [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820(v=ws.10).aspx)

By design, the maximum value of timeout is set to be 24 hours. Check out Microsoft support [forum](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/233477)

To achieve a larger window for timeout, you could consider maintaining session states in `SQL`, as suggested by @Marc.

Comment: I found this value but another problem appeared. I cannot set more than 23:59 hours there. And I need at least several.

Answer (score 4):

Try moving your session state into Sql ([link here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604)). This should persist an IIS restart/app pool recycle etc.

Answer (score 3):

Website Session.Timeout will work only when it is less than the application pool session timeout value; because whenever the application pool session timeout value is reached, that particular application pool will be restarted.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113287/Why-Session-Timeout-is-not-working-for-your-websit

Answer (score 1):

When the application is idle (no requests for some time), `IIS` may shut it down. This will destroy all `Sessions`.

`Authentication` stores it's data in a database and thus survives a restart.